# What is the volume of this octahedron?

Tags: volume

Can anyone help me with his problem? To me, this is a hard problem.

> What is the volume, in cubic centimeters, of a regular octahedron whose vertices are the centers of the faces of a cube whose edge measures 6 cm?

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach.** Divide the octahedron into two pyramids.  Use the fact that a pyramid, like a cone, has volume equal to one-third the area of the base times the height (altitude).